# Android app development for dummies book?

Tags: android

has anyone ever read/skimmed through this book? it is valuable/very helpful to people such as myself, who are complete noobs to android programming? I am thinking of purchasing one on amazon for $20 but dont know if its going to be a really helpful book.

Also, when i skim through the book on the amazon wesite, it seems to be missing alot of stuff. is that just amazon's preview method or is the book really that simple?

Comment: in my experience programming "dummies book" collection is really poor in content. By that I mean they really take you by the hand (nearly on a per click basis) but as soon as your try to get creative there is no info. you outgrow the book too fast in my opinion. If you know java then you should be able to get started easily with the examples on the android website.

Comment: thanks! thats what i wanted to hear.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Amazon preview only shows specific excepts. I learned exclusively from online tutorials and the official documentation, but if you prefer to learn from a book, check out this SO question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development

Comment: Sadly your link no longer exists.